# Synchronize AD changes in SQL server

Tags: sql, active-directory

Our sysadmin renamed several of our AD groups that we are using in SQL server.  The SQL login still has the old name.  Is there a way to synchronize AD and our SQL logins?

Comment: this is more suited to serverfault...

Comment: @marc_s - how is entering 100 users' AD accounts indivudally *so much easier* than entering one group?

Comment: @ck: or use the AD groups already - no problem for me. Just don't *replicate* users and/or groups into SQL e.g. create native SQL logins for AD groups.... just permission the AD group directly. Much easier - that's what I meant. Use the AD users/groups instead of building up the whole user/group mgmt infrastructure *again*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to manually rename them (SQL 2005 or later)

http://blogs.msdn.com/sqltips/archive/2005/10/10/479268.aspx